# Error calling C++/CLI constructor from C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, slimdx, managed-directx

I am trying to save and restore state by using a StateBlock in SlimDX via the following snippet:

```
StateBlockMask mask = new StateBlockMask(null) { RasterizerState = true };
var sb = new StateBlock(device.Device, mask);
```

Both StateBlockMask and StateBlock are classes. This gives me a compilation error:

```
'.ctor' is not supported by the language
```

Reading from some other posts here on SO, it seems that this is a problem that has to do with calling the managed code with the wrong arguments. In the source of SlimDX, I find:

```
StateBlock::StateBlock(SlimDX::Direct3D10::Device^ device, StateBlockMask mask)
```

I have no experience at all with C++/CLI, so I am wondering if there is something wrong here (like a missing or extra ^), or should I concentrate of faults on my side?

(NOTE: [This question has been cross-posted to gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/596656-slimdx-c-stateblock-contructor-problem-ctor-not-supported-by-the-language/), future users with the same question may also want to check for answers given there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `StateBlockMask` a struct?  If not, use `StateBlockMask^ mask` in the C++ constructor.

Comment: StateBlockMask is a class (added the info to the original post). Unfortunately, I cannot  recompile the C++ code at the current state of my project (not allowed).

Comment: @erik - then you are done with this project, you cannot use this C++/CLI code without fixing the bug.

Comment: You could write your own C++/CLI wrapper class that takes a StateBlockMask ^ and then within that wrapper class, call the StateBlock constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in SlimDX. You might want to use the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/list) to make sure it gets dealt with properly.

Comment: [Plagiarizing yourself?](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/596656-slimdx-c-stateblock-contructor-problem-ctor-not-supported-by-the-language/)... shame shame shame.  Hurry up and get 2k rep so you can edit questions and add links to cross-posts.  In the meantime you can always use comments.